# electron-builder skips publishing

Tags: github, electron, publish, electron-builder

I'm trying to release my app on github as the first release but after using the command :

```bash
GH_TOKEN=<token> electron-builder build -w -p 'onTagOrDraft'
```

the process looks smooth until publishing I get this error

```bash
• GitHub release not created  reason=existing type not compatible with publishing type tag=v1.0.0 version=1.0.0 existingType=release publishingType=draft
• skipped publishing  file=Primacy_pharma-Setup-1.0.0.exe.blockmap reason=existing type not compatible with publishing type tag=v1.0.0 version=1.0.0 existingType=release publishingType=draft
• skipped publishing  file=Primacy_pharma-Setup-1.0.0.exe reason=existing type not compatible with publishing type tag=v1.0.0 version=1.0.0 existingType=release publishingType=draft
• skipped publishing  file=latest.yml reason=existing type not compatible with publishing type tag=v1.0.0 version=1.0.0 existingType=release publishingType=draft
```

though I have my release as a draft on github.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.